# What is the best way to update a users email address in meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

So the built in [meteor](http://meteor.com) auth system stores user emails under the user like so:

```
emails: [ { address: d@s.com, verified: true} ]
```

Is there a 'meteoric' way to set a primary email, and update an email address (or add/remove emails)?

It seems to me if would be a great deal simpler if they were stored like so:

```
emails: { 'd@s.com': { verified: true } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggested object format makes no sense, because then how do I request that object? Normally I'd say `obj.emails[i].address`, now I have to say... what? `for (var key in obj.emails) { var email = obj.emails[key]; }`? That's much more complicated.

To update an email address, you should change the email address in the user record, mark it unverified, and initiate the verification process with [Account.sendVerificationEmail](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_sendverificationemail).

Comment: Well you would get the email with obj.emails[address], and then you don't have to look through an array. Presumably order doesn't matter, and uniqueness does, so it makes more sense as an object than an array.

Comment: But you need to know the address in advance to be able to look it up that way. That's not always the case. The object doesn't exist just to tell you whether it's verified or not, it exists to tell you which email addresses have been registered for that user.

Comment: Well there's also the need to find the first verified address, or save the primary email address (```profile.primaryEmail```, or ```emails[someNumber]: { verified: true, primary: true, address:someAddress }?```). Its easy enough to do, but its a little odd given how "batteries included" the rest of meteor seems to be. First coding world problems, haha.